# Is there a free SharePoint Site where I can work with SharePoint Designer

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

At work I am unable to create conditional workflows as I do not have access to SharePoint designer.  I do not have access to SharePoint Designer as I am not  a "Sharepoint developer" per our IT team even though I am a MS Access and MS Excel developer.

Is anyone aware of a site (paid or unpaid) that allows me to sign up for a SharePoint sandbox so I can at minimum practice creating workflows (note I have taken 2 classes, but without any interaction with SharePoint designer) .  I may be able to convince my IT department to provide me with SharePoint Designer permissions once I demonstrate I am SP Designer WF competent.  If not it would still be nice to create some prototype Workflows that may server as a business requirement document.

Note I use SharePoint Foundation 2013 at work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sharepoint designer is free tool, you can install it on your pc.

But what I read, you don't have a site collection where u can practice it. And you only want to sharepoint foundation. I would one of this.

1. Create a VM on my personal computer and install & configure sharepoint foundation farm then play with it.
2. Buy azure hosting and build a sharepoint foundation farm and play with it.
3. Another option is office 365 but I don't know if they have foundation  hosting.
4. You can also get a one site collection hosting from apps4rent on monthly basis and work with designer from your personal laptop. I would prefer this. Easy to get a site, no need to worry about farm installation and other headaches.